# Make a text link to call a function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have zero experience on jQuery. The meaning this code is to show and hide classes, but I would like a text link to activate 'more info' instead of the button.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script>
function unhide (arg) {
   jQuery('.' + arg).toggleClass('hidden'); }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<button onclick="unhide('more_info')">
   Click for More text
</button>

<div class="more_info hidden">
so much more info here
</div>

<div class="more_info hidden">
info appearing also here 
</div>
```

Comment: what is your css for `.hidden` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function unhide(arg) {
   
   jQuery('.' + arg).toggleClass('hidden');
   return false;
}
```

```css
.hidden{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a onclick="return unhide('more_info')" href="#">
   Click for More text
</a>

<div class="more_info hidden">
so much more info here
</div>

<div class="more_info hidden">
info appearing also here 
</div>
```